# How to set up CORS or OPTIONS for Rocket.rs

Tags: http, dart, rust, flutter-web, rust-rocket

I've got a backend running rocket.rs which my flutter web app sends a request to, but it can't get past the OPTIONS response.

I have tried adding CORS (rocket_cors) to the backend and having a options response, but it still sends back:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart:sdk_internal 124039:30                           get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart.lib.js 214:124  <fn>
```

I have added the following to my rocket project:

```rust
#[options("/")]
fn send_options<'a>(path: PathBuf) -> Response<'a> {
    let mut res = Response::new();
    res.set_status(Status::new(200, "No Content"));
    res.adjoin_header(ContentType::Plain);
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res
```

And my flutter app is running this request:

```
Future<String> fetchData() async {
  final data2 = await http.get("http://my-web-site.com").then((response) { // doesn't get past here
    return response.body; 
  });
  return data2;
}
```

Question: Is this the proper way to respond to OPTION requests, and if not, how can I implement it in rocket.rs?

Comment: For `GET` requests, the browser [skips the `OPTIONS` preflight and performs the `GET` directly.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) So perhaps you need to include the CORS headers in the `GET` handler as well.

Comment: @LambdaFairy that worked! Thanks, I can mark it answered if you want to put an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In order for a server to provide an external API it needs to be able to deal with Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). CORS is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate which origins (domain, protocol, or port) that a browser should permit loading of resources.

You can create a fairing to handle CORS globally for your app. A very permissive version would be as follows, but of course, you'll have to tailor to your specific application.

### Rocket 0.4

```rust
use rocket::http::Header;
use rocket::{Request, Response};
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};

pub struct CORS;

impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Add CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response
        }
    }

    fn on_response(&self, request: &Request, response: &mut Response) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

### Rocket 0.5

```rust
use rocket::http::Header;
use rocket::{Request, Response};
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};

pub struct CORS;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Add CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, _request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

You just have to attach the fairing like this:

```rust
rocket::ignite().attach(CORS)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`rocket_cors`](https://docs.rs/rocket_cors) crate.

```rust
use rocket::http::Method;
use rocket_cors::{AllowedOrigins, CorsOptions};

let cors = CorsOptions::default()
    .allowed_origins(AllowedOrigins::all())
    .allowed_methods(
        vec![Method::Get, Method::Post, Method::Patch]
            .into_iter()
            .map(From::from)
            .collect(),
    )
    .allow_credentials(true);

rocket::ignite().attach(cors.to_cors().unwrap())
```

*You can learn more about CORS and Access Control headers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers)*

Comment: Things change a bit when you start using v 0.5.0 and up of rocket and async https://rocket.rs/master/guide/fairings/

Comment: Sure, but 0.5 has not been officially released yet, so I'll update the answer then.

Comment: In 0.5, you'll need to add `#[rocket::async_trait]` attribute to the implementation and make on_response `async` with a lifetime.

Comment: you forgot to put <'r> in on_response. It should be `on_response<'r>`

Comment: does the wildcard star really work? I think it doesn't and you'll need to do something like `let origin = _request.headers().get_one("origin").unwrap();` and `let headers = _request.headers().iter().map(|h| h.name.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(", ");` for origin and headers

Comment: Careful. This code ignores the so-called [wildcard exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards).

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me with rocket 0.5.0-rc.2 and no other dependencies. It's based on the answers above and some internet searches.

```
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};
use rocket::http::Header;
use rocket::log::private::debug;
use rocket::serde::json::Json;
use rocket::{Request, Response};

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .attach(Cors)
        .mount("/", routes![index, all_options, insert])
}

/// Some getter
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello CORS"
}

/// Some setter
#[post("/", data = "<data>")]
async fn insert(data: Json<Vec<String>>) {
    debug!("Received data");
}

/// Catches all OPTION requests in order to get the CORS related Fairing triggered.
#[options("/<_..>")]
fn all_options() {
    /* Intentionally left empty */
}

pub struct Cors;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for Cors {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing Fairing",
            kind: Kind::Response,
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, _request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, GET",
        ));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

Comment: God bless you man.

Comment: Should `.attach` come before `.mount`?

Answer (score 9):

This did the trick for me:

```
use rocket::http::Header;
use rocket::{Request, Response};
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};

pub struct CORS;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Attaching CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, _request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

And you have to attach it in the function with the launch macro:

```
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .attach(CORS)
        .mount("/index", routes![index])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambda Fairy's comment answered it for me.
I put it all in the `GET` Handler:

```rust
#[get("/")]
fn get_handler<'a>() -> Response<'a> {
    let mut res = Response::new();
    res.set_status(Status::new(200, "No Content"));
    res.adjoin_header(ContentType::Plain);
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.adjoin_raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.set_sized_body(Cursor::new("Response")); 
    res
```

Answer (score 2):

To have Cross Origin Resource Sharing support you must intercept responses
sent by your Rocket server. You want to implement a middleware to achieve that,
on Rocket you must implement the `Fairing` trait on a `struct` in order to
achieve that.

### Rocket v0.5.x (Not stable)

If you on search Rocket's documentation for version 0.5.x.

```
Trait implemented by fairings: Rocket’s structured middleware.
```

[Source](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/fairing/trait.Fairing.html#)

> You must decorate the  `Fairing` `trait` implementation with the [rocket::async-trait](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/fairing/trait.Fairing.html#async-trait)
> attribute.

```rust
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};
use rocket::http::Header;
use rocket::{Request, Response};

pub struct Cors;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for Cors {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing Middleware",
            kind: Kind::Response,
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self,
        request: &'r Request<'_>,
        response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new(
            "access-control-allow-origin",
            "https://example.com",
        ));
        response.set_header(Header::new(
            "access-control-allow-methods",
            "GET, PATCH, OPTIONS",
        ));
    }
}
```

On your `main.rs` file, you must attach the middleware:

```rust
mod config;
mod middleware;
mod routes;

use self::config::Config;

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

#[launch]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
    let config = Config::new();

    rocket::custom(&config.server_config)
        .attach(middleware::cors::Cors)
        .mount(
            "/api/v1",
            routes![routes::index],
        )
}
```

### Rocket 0.4.x (Stable)

Refer to [Ibraheem Ahmed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64904947/9888500)

Comment: No need to add another crate, just use `#[rocket::async_trait]` as shown in [the docs you linked to](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/fairing/trait.Fairing.html#async-trait).

Comment: Good example with putting the CORS related code into a separate middleware module.

Answer (score 2):

in case someone is looking for rocket>= rc5.0

```
use rocket::http::Header;
use rocket::{Request, Response};
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};

pub struct CORS;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Add CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response
       }
    }


    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, req: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jesus. After several hours I finally got it working. First and foremost, a small warning: We are working with highly unstable code and this answer may be obsolete by the time you're reading. The edit from matthewscottgordon in Ibraheem Ahmeed's answer pointed me to the right direction.

We're going to be using the [`rocket_cors`](https://docs.rs/rocket_cors/latest/rocket_cors/) crate.

#### 1. Install an old version of Rust Nightly. As of Jan 22nd, Rust Nightly V 1.6.0 breaks mongodb 2.1.0.

Do this just in case the latest nightly isn't compiling.

You can do this in the following fashion:

> rustup override set nightly-2021-11-10
> This will download 1.58 nightly.

#### 2. Add the rocket_cors dependency. As of now, the master version has a 1.6.0 release, which targets rocket's 0.5.0-rc.1 release

> rocket_cors = { git = "https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors", branch = "master" }

This is my cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = {version ="0.5.0-rc.1", features=["json"]}
rocket_cors = { git = "https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors", branch = "master" }
reqwest = {version = "0.11.6", features = ["json"] }
serde= {version = "1.0.117", features= ["derive"]}
mongodb = "2.1.0"
rand = "0.8.4"
```

#### 3. Add the following to your main Rocket function:

```rust
extern crate rocket;

use std::error::Error;
use rocket_cors::{AllowedOrigins, CorsOptions};

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let cors = CorsOptions::default()
        .allowed_origins(AllowedOrigins::all())
        .allowed_methods(
            vec![Method::Get, Method::Post, Method::Patch]
                .into_iter()
                .map(From::from)
                .collect(),
        )
        .allow_credentials(true)
        .to_cors()?;

    // let path = concat!(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"), "/public");
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes![index, upload::upload, post_favorites])
        .attach(cors)
        .launch()
        .await?;


    Ok(())
}
```

If by any chance this answer *doesn't work for you*, be sure to check out [rocket_cors repository](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/tree/master/examples) for up to date examples. The example above was used with the [fairing.rs](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/blob/master/examples/fairing.rs) file

Check out the repo's [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/blob/master/Cargo.toml) file.

To check for the default values in `let cors`, (if using VS Code, and the Rust extension) hover over `CorsOptions` with your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working for my service with Rocket v0.5-rc thanks to the answers here and [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/2142#issuecomment-1086660848).

For my use case I had no need to customize the CORS headers for specific requests. If you have more elaborate requirements, use [rocket_cors](https://docs.rs/rocket_cors/latest/rocket_cors/).

Create a CORS [Fairing](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/fairings/) to set the CORS headers on every response.

```rust
use rocket::fairing::{Fairing, Info, Kind};
use rocket::http::{Header, Method, Status};
use rocket::{Request, Response};

pub struct CORS;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Add CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response,
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        if request.method() == Method::Options {
            response.set_status(Status::NoContent);
            response.set_header(Header::new(
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "POST, PATCH, GET, DELETE",
            ));
            response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        }

        response.set_header(Header::new(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "http://localhost:3000",
        ));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

Then affix this fairing to your rocket with `rocket::build().attach(cors::CORS)` and you're all set.

Full credit to the answers above as this was heavily inspired by them. The important part that was missing was setting the `NoContent` status for all options requests. Thankfully [Domenico Gaeni's example](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/2142#issuecomment-1086660848) included this:

```rust
response.set_status(Status::NoContent)
```

Without this Rocket would 404 on every option request. By setting the status here in the fairing there's no need to define any special routes to serve option requests.

If you're using this note the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be customized to your use case. I hardcoded it to `http://localhost:3000` as I couldn't bring myself to use `*` in the event someone copy-and-pasted it in full.

In real life you'll likely want to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` based on the request [origin header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header) or [Rocket.toml config](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/configuration/#rockettoml) or both so as to support your local development and test/staging/production servers.

Comment: This solution has the caveat that Rocket logs a 404 for each preflight request. It works fine as the browser looks at the response headers on the preflight and ignore the status code (in Safari at least). Still, the server log is annoying. You can suppress the error log by adding this hack after setting the status: `let _ = response.body_mut().take();`.